# Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I'm updating two related Entity objects lets call them Order and OrderDetails. Every field aside from the primary fields are nullable in the database.

Below is a code snippet:

```
ClientEntities ce = new ClientEntities();
    Order order = (from p in ce.Orders
                                 where p.OrderID == OrderID                                
                                 select p).FirstOrDefault();

    decimal discountpercent = decimal.Parse(rntb_DiscountPercent.DbValue.ToString());

                        foreach (OrderDetail oDetail in order.OrderDetails)
                        {
                            decimal listprice = iDetail.PurchasedItem.ListPrice.GetValueOrDefault();
                            decimal discountvalue = listprice * (discountpercent / 100);
                            decimal paidprice = Decimal.Round(listprice - discountvalue, 2);

                            oDetail.ClientAmountReceived = paidprice;
                        }
                        order.DiscountPercent = rntb_DiscountPercent.Value;
                        ce.SaveChanges();
```

When the context goes to commit the changes to the db I get the following error:

> System.InvalidCastException: Object
>   cannot be cast from DBNull to other
>   types.
>
> ```
> at System.DBNull.System.IConvertible.ToInt16(IFormatProvider
> ```
>
> provider)
>       at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object
>   value, Type conversionType,
>   IFormatProvider provider)
>       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Evaluator.Cast(Object
>   value, Type clrPrimitiveType)
>       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Evaluator.Visit(DbCastExpression
>   node)
>       at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbCastExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1
>   visitor)
>       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Evaluator.Evaluate(DbExpression
>   node, PropagatorResult row, Propagator
>   parent)
>       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Project(DbProjectExpression
>   node, PropagatorResult row, TypeUsage
>   resultType)
>       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Visit(DbProjectExpression
>   node)
>       at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.DbProjectExpression.Accept[TResultType](DbExpressionVisitor`1
>   visitor)
>       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.Propagator.Propagate(UpdateTranslator
>   parent, EntitySet table,
>   DbQueryCommandTree umView)
>       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.d_*0.MoveNext()
>       at System.Linq.Enumerable.d*_71`1.MoveNext()
>       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateCommandOrderer..ctor(IEnumerable`1
>   commands, UpdateTranslator translator)
>       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.ProduceCommands()
>       at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
>       at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityAdapter.Update(IEntityStateManager
>   entityCache)
>       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions
>   options)
>       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges()
>       at BSpace.InvoicePage.lbtn_CalculateDiscount_Click(Object
>   o, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Projects\Client\trunk\Client
>   Application\Source\ClientProject\OrderPage.aspx.cs:line
>   1069
>       at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)
>       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)
>       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>       at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)
>       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData)
>       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

In the database Orders.DiscountPercent is (float, null) and OrderDetails.ClientAmountReceived is (money, null).

Not sure why this is happening since these are the only two fields I'm updating. I've tried making sure there's data in every field and still get this error. I've also checked the data model file to make sure that the table mappings are correct for all associated fields.
OrderDetails.ClientAmountReceived translates to a Nullable and Order.DiscountPercent translates to a Nullable.

I can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in any of the values that you are changing. In fact, your new values are of non-nullable types at the places where they are being set.

Since the datatype that is failing is `Int16`, I would check all of the mappings to `short` values to look for any non-nullable properties mapped to nullable columns.

Comment: I've actually checked that as well. I went into the Entity table mapping and forced those values to be nullable with no success. It seems like Entity's table mapping doesn't explicitly set the Nullable property but the type still comes through as a `short?` from the application based on its definition in Model.Designer.cs.